# TCP optimisation

Tags: qt, sockets, winsock

I've written a code using SOL_SOCKET protocol but getting error as 10043 (error in socket).

The code is as follows:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<QDebug>
//#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/****************************************/
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
/****************************************/

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    //hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = SOL_SOCKET;
    //hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

#define DEFAULT_PORT "10990"

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

// Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
// the call to getaddrinfo
ptr=result;

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
    ptr->ai_protocol);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

    int rcvbuf = 8192;  /* recv buffer size */
    int z = setsockopt(ConnectSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,
    (char*)&rcvbuf,sizeof(rcvbuf));

    do {
            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       } while (iResult > 0);

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run it shows::

```
Error in socket:10043
```

I googled it and found that the error is because of wrong protocol for the socket type,I tried to find the correct protocol and socket type match but couldn't find.I tried every possible socket option and protocol match.
Any body facing the same problem?

Comment: You *do* know that Qt have its own set of [network classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html)? You don't really need to use raw socket calls if you're already use Qt.

Comment: I'm not using Qt network classes because I want to increase recieve buffer size by using setsockopt().

Comment: You can do that with [`QTcpSocket` as well](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption). Any socket API which doesn't allow you to set options would be pretty useless.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Can I use setsockopt() with Qt network sockets also?

Comment: Yes, use the `setSocketOption` member function, whose reference I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the wrong value in the `ai_protocol` field. It needs to be one of the `IPPROTO_` constants (like e.g. `IPPROTO_TCP` or `IPPROTO_ICMP`).

`SOL_SOCKET` is used to set [socket options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (like you do later in the code).

You should normally *not* set that member, except to zero.

Comment: Now its showing error 10044 i.e family incorrect.which family does SOL_SOCKET belong?

Comment: @user2617519 You shouldn't set `SOL_SOCKET` *anywhere* in the `addrinfo` structure. The `SOL_*` constants are *only* used for socket options (i.e. `setsockopt`/`getsockopt`). Using `AF_INET` for family and `SOCK_STREAM` for socket type is enough.